# Removing a page from the header menu

Tags: menus

[My site](http://joshuafox.com) is using the Hemmingway theme, I have a menu in the header.

This is the menu whose structure results  from assigning a "parent" on a page's edit form.

One of my pages is less important and should not appear in the menu. (It is  accessible through links from the body of  other pages.)

I went to Appearance->Menus (/wp-admin/nav-menus.php) and removed this page under the Menu Structure list (there is only one menu there, "Menu 1". Yet this page still appears in the header menu.

How do I remove it from the header menu?

Comment: Have you tried editing the menu properly?  From the admin menu, Appearance > Menus

Comment: I guess you are using any cache plugin or the menu is using Transient to cache the menu state. Let the cache be cleared.

Comment: @jdm2112 Yes, I edited the menu from Appearance->Menus. There is one menu there, called Menu1, but it doesn't appear to affect the header menu. The checkbox  "Theme locations Primary Menu" is unchecked. When I check it, I get a "Wordpress Failure Notice" page reading  simply "Are you sure you want to do this?" but with no OK button or any other control.

But what I want to do is simply exclude a page from the header menu provided by  the Hemmingway theme.

Comment: I should add that I am talking abourt the menu whose structure results  from assigning a "parent" on a page's edit form.

Comment: When I use Firefox and check " "Theme locations Primary Menu", then this Menu 1 is indeed used as the header menu. So, I could rebuild the menu and assign it this way. But I would rather just use the menu based on the assignment of pages to a parent in each page's edit form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually created a menu under Appearance->Menus and then assigned this as the Primary Menu.

This worked, but required me to manually reproduce the structure of the menu: The structure created by assigning a parent in each page's admin is now simply ignored. I would still like a way to use the default menu, which is generated straight  from the parenthood relations, yet make modifications like omitting a page from the menu.